# How to add text inside <> tags using builder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, builder

So I am trying to build an XML document for export. But I need to add extra text inside the headers and can't figure out how.

```
def as_xml
  require 'rubygems'
  require 'builder'

  builder = Builder::XmlMarkup.new(:target=>STDOUT, :indent=>2)

  xml = builder.propertyList { |b|
    b.description(self.description);
    self.highlights.each do |h|
      b.highlight(h);
    end
  }
end
```

returns:

```
<propertyList>
  <description>"Description goes here"
  </description>
  <highlight>Highlight 1</highlight>
  <highlight>Highlight 2</highlight>
</propertyList>
```

Is there a way to make it so that I can add an ID attribute to the highlight tags?
Such as `<highlight id=1>`, etc.

Also wondering if there a way to define whether or not a tag should be self-closing using builder?

e.g.:

```
<auction date=self.auctionDate />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass in attributes as a hash for the secondary argument:

```
self.highlights.each_with_index do |h, i|
  b.highlight(h, id: i+1);
end

=> <highlight id='1'>Highlight 1</highlight>
=> <highlight id='2'>Highlight 2</highlight>
```

And if you pass only a hash, you can get a self-closing node:

```
b.auction(date: 'someDate')

=> <auction date='someDate' />
```